# How do I create a random method name

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp, unobtrusive-javascript

I plan on using JSONP to call an external web service to get around the fact that I don't want to create a global function that could potentially conflict with the calling page. I thought that creating a random function name and passing it up would work.  Something like this:

```
<script src="www.foo.com/b?cb=d357534">
```

where `cb` is the callback function name, the server would return

```
d357534({my json data});
```

What I want to know is how to create the random function name, I'm sure I could use `eval` but is this the best way to go about it?

Essentially, what I am trying to do is this:

```
var d + Math.floor(Math.random()*1000001) = function(){...
```

Comment: If you are creating lots of these, don't forget to delete the functions when you are done with them, or you will leak memory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do what you want. You need to save the function name somewhere so that you can pass it to the server, but you can do that inside of a local scope to avoid polluting your global namespace.

```
var functionName = 'd' + Math.floor(Math.random()*1000001);
window[functionName] = function() { ... }
```

Comment: you can also put a check in, to verify that it does not exist, prior to creating it.

Comment: Why this is not working for `functionName` that has '.'(dot) in it.???
OR you can also say that if we define function name like OOP convention then it is not working??
For example..  `window['Incident'+randomeint+'.showList']=function{ ... }`

Answer (score 1):

To make a randomly-named global variable you could do this:

```
window['randomvar' + Math.floor(Math.random()*1000001)] = function() { ... };
```

now of course you've got the problem of remembering the random name somewhere.  You could make up a random name for *that* variable too.  Then you'd have to remember the name of *that* variable, so that you could look at its value and then know how to find your function.  After a while, things are going to start getting weird.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't just use a counter and increment it each time you need a new function:

```
var name = "callback" + window.COUNTER++;
window[name] = function() { ... };
```

If you want to avoid littering the global namespace with too many references you could (and should) attach the counter and callbacks to a single global object:

```
var JSONP = window.JSONP;
var name = "callback" + JSONP.COUNTER++;
JSONP[name] = function() { ... };
```

In this case you could call the method like this:

```
JSONP.callback_12(json);
```

Of coarse you have to initialize the `JSONP`object and the `COUNTER` variable first.